# Multiple overriding of a type member

Tags: scala, types

Let's have this simplified code:

```
class Base {
  self =>
  type Actual <: Base {type Actual = self.Actual}

  def me: Actual = this.asInstanceOf[Actual]
}

class A extends Base {
  override type Actual = A
}

class B extends A {
  override type Actual = B
}

println((new B).me)
```

I want the `me` to always have a proper return type (for fluent interface). Unfortunately this code is crashing with:

```
test.scala:13: error: overriding type Actual in class A, which equals this.A;
 type Actual has incompatible type
  override type Actual = B
                ^
one error found
```

**How to implemented the desired behavior and why is it crashing on a second type member override?**

Comment: you can use `self.type`, instead of defining a type member

Answer (score 1):

This is usually achieved through f bounded polymorphism.

```
class Base[Actual <: Base[Actual]] {   
  def me: Actual
}

class A extends Base[A]

class B extends Base[A]
```

If you would like `B` to extend `A` you need `A` to pass through a type param again:

```
class A[Actual <: Base[Actual]] extends Base[Actual]
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution, I mistakenly believed that type parameters and members have same power, so I was trying to express it via type members (I liked them more, but I see now that I'll have to use type parameters).

Comment: How does one instantiate the `A` when `B` is extending `A`?

Comment: You'll need to provide a type argument, usually in such situations you shouldn't need to instantiate `A`. The root class should contain enough information about `A` and `B`, I don't know your particular circumstance though.

Answer (score 1):

@flavian's answer is right. For reasons why such multiple overriding doesn't work, check this discussion https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scala-user/si51jb9RS68

Particularly, this point:

> To override a class member, the type of the overriding has to
>   "subsume" the type of the overridden member. (Spec section 5.1.4)
>
> For type aliases, "subsume" means they have to be equivalent. (Spec
>   section 3.5.2, toward the end.)

So, you are able to write this, because type `A` is obviously equivalent ot `A`:

```
class B extends A {
  override type Actual = A
}
```

But types `A` and `B` aren't equivalent, that's why you can't override type `A` with type `B`.

Comment: Thanks for explanation, I thought type parameters and type members have same "power". It doesn't seem to be the case if I cannot express the f-bounded polymorphism via type members :-/.